# How to query Facebook for awaiting "request" (From request API)

Tags: android, ios, facebook, facebook-graph-api

We are doing a mobile app, where its possible to send out virtual goods through requests. I have figured out how to make the users actually send the requests, but I cannot figure out how to poll awaiting requests from the receivers end?

Answer (score 0):

Seems like I found it(FQL)

SELECT ... FROM apprequest WHERE app_id = A

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/apprequest